# What is the cause of this Mac application signing error using the jpackage utility?

Tags: java, macos, deployment, code-signing

I'm attempting to package a Java application as an app bundle for Mac (Sonoma 14.3.1) using the `jpackage` utility. Running in a bash shell in the Mac terminal, the relevant command is

```bash
sudo jpackage \
    -i deploy \
    -d deploy-mac \
    -n "MyApp Name" \
    --type app-image \
    --main-class "com.my.class.MyClass" \
    --main-jar "MyApp.jar" \
    --app-version 1.0 \
    --copyright "..." \
    --description "..." \
    --icon "..." \
    --vendor "..." \
    --mac-app-category "public.app-category.education" \
    --verbose \
    --mac-sign \
    --mac-signing-keychain login \
    --mac-signing-key-user-name "XYZ Signing ID"
```

where "XYZ Signing ID" is the ID of a valid Apple Developer ID certificate. I'm currently using JDK 21.

The process completes without issue when I omit the final three parameters (i.e., `--mac-sign`, `--mac-signing-keychain`, and `--mac-signing-key-user-name`), but this requires a great deal of ex post facto voodoo to ensure the application runs and is accepted by Apple's "Gatekeeper".

When the three parameters are included, the command fails with the cryptic error:

```
[12:02:04.264] Running /usr/bin/security
[12:02:04.289] Command [PID: 33259]:
    /usr/bin/security find-certificate -c Developer ID Application: XYZ Signing ID -a login
[12:02:04.291] Returned: 0

[12:02:04.291] Running /usr/bin/security
[12:02:04.309] Command [PID: 33260]:
    /usr/bin/security find-certificate -c Developer ID Application: XYZ Signing ID -a -p login
[12:02:04.309] Returned: 0

[12:02:04.312] Running /usr/bin/openssl
[12:02:04.321] Command [PID: 33261]:
    /usr/bin/openssl x509 -noout -subject -in /private/var/folders/_g/dwvgjlm50sl23mp5w7s3cf8c0000gn/T/tempfile17263379665633563715.tmp
[12:02:04.321] Output:
    unable to load certificate
    140704282142656:error:09FFF06C:PEM routines:CRYPTO_internal:no start line:/AppleInternal/Library/BuildRoots/4e1473ee-9f66-11ee-8daf-cedaeb4cabe2/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/libressl/libressl-3.3/crypto/pem/pem_lib.c:694:Expecting: TRUSTED CERTIFICATE
[12:02:04.322] Returned: 1

[12:02:04.322] java.io.IOException: Command [/usr/bin/openssl, x509, -noout, -subject, -in, /private/var/folders/_g/dwvgjlm50sl23mp5w7s3cf8c0000gn/T/tempfile17263379665633563715.tmp] exited with 1 code
    at jdk.jpackage/jdk.jpackage.internal.Executor.executeExpectSuccess(Executor.java:90)
    at jdk.jpackage/jdk.jpackage.internal.IOUtils.exec(IOUtils.java:229)
    ...
[12:02:04.324] jdk.jpackage.internal.PackagerException: Bundler Mac Application Image skipped because of a configuration problem: Signature explicitly requested but no signing certificate found 
Advice to fix: Specify a valid mac-signing-key-user-name and mac-signing-keychain
    at jdk.jpackage/jdk.jpackage.internal.Arguments.generateBundle(Arguments.java:702)
    at jdk.jpackage/jdk.jpackage.internal.Arguments.processArguments(Arguments.java:555)
    ...
[12:02:04.323] No certificate found matching [Developer ID Application: XYZ Signing ID] using keychain [login]
```

As is apparent, the signing certificate exists and is valid (both calls to /usr/bin/security) succeed, but the call to `openssl` fails with a parsing error on a temporary file when validating the certificate. Worse, the temporary file (presumably containing the certificate data) changes on each invocation and is deleted before `jpackage` aborts, meaning the file can't be inspected. I've tried using the `--temp` parameter to specify a temporary directory, but this doesn't work (the application behaviour is unchanged).

I have no idea what could be causing this error or how to go about diagnosing it. I suspect it's a bug in `jpackage`, but I'm not using any features that wouldn't be common to most Java applications. Hence, unless *everyone* trying to build a Java-based app bundle for Mac is running into this error, I must be doing something wrong.

My question is: **What is the cause of this error, and is there any simple fix or workaround?**

---

On the off-chance that there is no simple workaround, I've included my own (more exhaustive) workaround as an answer below.

Answer (score 0):

### Workaround

Using JDK 21, I was able to get the application to run and Apple's notarization tool to successfully notarize the app bundle using the following workaround.

Assume the .JAR file is `deploy/MyApp.jar` and that XCode is installed. Also assume that "Developer ID Application: XYZ Signing ID (ABCDEFGHIJK)" is a valid Apple Developer ID certificate registered on the local (i.e., `login`) keychain.

First, run `jpackage` without the `--mac-sign` parameters, i.e.,

```bash
sudo jpackage \
    -i deploy \
    -d deploy-mac \
    -n "MyApp Name" \
    --type app-image \
    --main-class "com.my.class.MyClass" \
    --main-jar "MyApp.jar" \
    --app-version 1.0 \
    --copyright "..." \
    --description "..." \
    --icon "..." \
    --vendor "..." \
    --mac-app-category "public.app-category.education" \
    --verbose
```

This should create `deploy-mac/MyApp Name.app` as an app bundle.

Create file `resource/mac-entitlements.plist` with contents:

```
<dict>
    <key>com.apple.security.cs.allow-jit</key>
    <true/>
    <key>com.apple.security.cs.allow-unsigned-executable-memory</key>
    <true/>
    <key>com.apple.security.cs.allow-dyld-environment-variables</key>
    <true/>
    <key>com.apple.security.cs.disable-library-validation</key>
    <true/>
    <key>com.apple.security.cs.disable-executable-page-protection</key>
    <true/>
</dict>
```

Create bash script `resource/notarize-for-mac` (give it executable permissions) with contents:

```bash
#!/bin/sh
# notarize-for-mac
# Notarize Java executable for Mac distribution.
#
# Batch file must be run with the project directory as the working directory.

# variables
USER_ID="your.apple.id@wherever.com"
ENTITLEMENTS_FILE="resource/mac-entitlements.plist"
CERT_ID="Developer ID Application: XYZ Signing ID (ABCDEFGHIJK)"

# derived variables
APP_NAME="MyApp Name"
APP_PATH="deploy-mac/$APP_NAME.app"
ZIP_PATH="deploy-mac/$APP_NAME.zip"
BIN_PATH_MACOS="$APP_PATH/Contents/MacOS"
BIN_PATH_HOMELIB="$APP_PATH/Contents/runtime/Contents/Home/lib"
BIN_PATH_RUN_MACOS="$APP_PATH/Contents/runtime/Contents/MacOS"

# do NOT change the order of these; notarization will fail
BINARIES=(\
    "$BIN_PATH_HOMELIB/jspawnhelper" \
    "$BIN_PATH_RUN_MACOS/libjli.dylib" \
    "$BIN_PATH_MACOS/$APP_NAME" \
)

DYLIBS=(\
    "$BIN_PATH_HOMELIB/"*".dylib" \
    "$BIN_PATH_HOMELIB/server/"*".dylib" \
    "$BIN_PATH_RUN_MACOS/"*".dylib" \
)

if [[ "$1" = "sign" ]]
then
    # sign the DLLs first
    codesign \
        --sign "$CERT_ID" \
        --force \
        --options runtime \
        -vvv "${DYLIBS[@]}"

    # sign the binaries; these MUST be signed with --strict so that the
    # the Gatekeeper doesn't choke on them; the --entitlements are needed
    # because the Gatekeeper doesn't normally allow JIT compiling (thanks
    # for nothing, Apple)
    codesign \
        --sign "$CERT_ID" \
        --force \
        --strict \
        --entitlements "$ENTITLEMENTS_FILE" \
        --options runtime \
        -vvv "${BINARIES[@]}"

    # sign the bundle
    codesign \
        --sign "$CERT_ID" \
        --verify \
        --force \
        --options runtime \
        -vvv "$APP_PATH"

elif [[ "$1" = "setpwd" ]]
then
    # load user ID/password information onto keychain
    echo "Enter notary tool password: \c"
    read NOTARY_PASSWORD

    xcrun notarytool store-credentials "notarytool-password" \
        --apple-id "$USER_ID" \
        --password "$NOTARY_PASSWORD"

elif [[ "$1" = "notarize" ]]
then
    # package as .zip file
    rm "$ZIP_PATH"
    ditto -c -k --keepParent "$APP_PATH" "$ZIP_PATH"

    # submit app for notarization
    xcrun notarytool submit "$ZIP_PATH" \
        --keychain-profile "notarytool-password" \
        --wait

    # if the command returns an error code, use
    #    xcrun notarytool log <ticket_ID> --keychain-profile "notarytool-password" \ 
    #       notary_error_log.json
    # to obtain a list of errors to remedy

elif [[ "$1" = "staple" ]]
then
    # staple Gatekeeper ticket to signed application
    xcrun stapler staple "$APP_PATH"

elif [[ "$1" = "zip" ]]
then
    # zip stapled app for distribution
    rm "$ZIP_PATH"
    ditto -c -k --keepParent "$APP_PATH" "$ZIP_PATH"
fi
```

One time only, call

```bash
./resource/notarize-for-mac setpwd
```

and enter your [app-specific password](https://support.apple.com/en-ca/102654) to load it into the "notarytool-password" ID on the local keychain. You can alternatively insert your password directly into the script, but this is a bad idea if you need to share/distribute the script, and is bad security practice to boot.

Once this is done, every time you want to sign the application, use (in order):

`./resource/notarize-for-mac sign` - signs the application bundle
`./resource/notarize-for-mac notarize` - submit the bundle to Apple's notarization service
`./resource/notarize-for-mac staple` - staple the notarization ticket to the bundle (assuming notarization succeeds)
`./resource/notarize-for-mac zip` - procure a zipped version of the bundle for distribution

This process worked for me as of JDK 21.